# Get a views result using PHP code, and iterate the proper way

Tags: views

I have a view called all_projects_list. This view fetches Fields (not nodes), and i'd like to get it by code, and iterate on it. I managed to do this by using:

```
$view = views_get_view_result('all_projects_list', 'default');
foreach($view as $project){
    print_r($project->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_project_code['und'][0]['value']);
}
```

Which as you can see is very, very dirty.
Is there a Drupal way of doing this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

It's not very different from what you do, but here's example code from a project of mine, showing how I usually do it

```
$view = views_get_view('a_view');
$view->preview('panel_pane_1', array($node->nid));
foreach ($view->result as $tid) {
  print $tid->taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy_tid;
}
```

Based on the function documentation

> To be called externally, probably by an AJAX handler of some flavor. Can also be called when views are embedded, as this guarantees normalized output.

I've always assumed that [preview()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21includes%21view.inc/function/view%3A%3Apreview/7) is the proper way to do it, and it has served me well on a number of occasions.

Comment: Is this really the only way of doing this? This is really not pretty (having to get the view data twice just so you can parse it)

Comment: You're not getting the data twice, you're loading the view, then executing it via preview(). You can also use execute(). What are you trying to achieve by iterating through? Views has a very robust API which you can do just about anything in if you can decipher it.

Answer (score 4):

you can do this

```
$view = views_get_view($view_name);
$view->set_display($display_id);
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
$total = $view->total_rows;
```

to get the total number. If you want to iterate, maybe

```
$result = views_get_view_result($view_name, $display_id);
foreach($result as result) {
  // do something.
}
```

Note: this depends on use pager to display all results, otherwise you will get only limited results.

Comment: i facing an issue with views_get_view_result($view_name, $display_id); because it returning entire fields that coming in sql query, even those fields are not mentioned in view display settings. How can I get the exact row of data that we are getting from views template file as $rows variable?