# In custom form, how can I add a select field using "entity reference view"

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have an entity reference view (views block with entity reference display of a list of nodes that have "Certification" checked (boolean)). I am able to use this view from the content type manage fields config, i.e. http://localhost:8888/admin/structure/types/manage/certification-credit/fields/field_certification_exam_id/field-settings and it gives me a select list of all entities with that condition.

Is there a Drupal function to invoke this view to create a select field programmatically in my custom form? I've searched high and low and can't find anything about this.

Comment: Just to be clear: You are trying to replace an auto-complete with a select field?

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32825/get-a-views-result-using-php-code-and-iterate-the-proper-way) is what you're after; i.e. load the view and desired display, extract the results, build up an options array, and add it to a normal select element

Comment: Yessir, @Clive this is exactly what I was looking for! Can you answer so I can accept, or flag as duplicate of your link?

Comment: @longboardnode Done!